# Write permissions for Network service in network folder

Tags: permissions, team-foundation-server

I'm trying to setup Team Foundation Server (TFS) authomatic backups, and to do that I need to set up a network folder for database backups. When trying to set folder path I receive a message from TFS saying SQl Server service has not permissions for this folder.

Looking in services I see SQLExpress service is run under *Network service* account, and lookin in that remote folder from my computer I see *Network service* has all permissions for that folder, so I can't grant any more permissions from this computer. Going to the othe computer I can't (or don't know how to do it) assign permission to *Network service* account from the other computer.

What do I need to do?

Comment: Did you try assigning permissions to to computer account (i.e, domain\computername$)?

Comment: I think network is not configured under a domain

Comment: Then you can't do it that way. Network Service = "Computer Account" (COMPUTER$) on remote systems

Comment: My advice would be to put the backup on the local machine and use something like Cobian Backup to push it someplace else.

Comment: @NathanC I like Cobian Backup but in this case it's not possible, TFS stores repositories in SQLServer not files and it's SQLServer Service which needs permissions to write in that folder, and plus, TFS requires backup folder not to be local

Comment: You can use SQL Management Studio to create a job that backs up the database manually. You don't *have* to use TFS to do your backup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand that this isn't on a windows domain, then:

1. Create a local administrative level account (say "TFSSQL")
2. Set the SQL Service to run under that account
3. Start up SQL again and make sure TFS is running fine
4. On the remote computer, add `TFSCOMPUTERNAME\TFSSQL" as having Modify rights to the share and NTFS permissions of the backup shared folder
5. Back on the TFS server, log out and log back in as TFSSQL
6. Go in and run the backup wizard again.

That should do it.